# Computing weighted average using lowess mthod in R

Tags: r, smoothing

I am trying to use the lowess method from R to compute the weighted average of a data set which is not uniformly distributed along x axis. For example, the first 5 data points are like this, where the first column is the x and the second is the y.

> 375.0   2040.0
>      472.0   5538.0
>      510.0   4488.0
>      573.0   2668.0
>      586.0   7664.0

I used the following command in R:

```
x<-read.table(add,header=FALSE,sep="\t")
y<-lowess(x[,1],x[,2],f=0.01)
write.table(y, file = results , sep = "\t", col.names =FALSE, row.names =FALSE)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

The green line shows the average computed by the smooth function in matlab (tri-cubic kernel), and the red line is the average line computed by lowess method in R. The blue dots are the data points.
 I can't find why the method in R does not work. Do you have any idea?

Here is a [link](http://temp-share.com/show/gFHK22S6Y/data?w=AAA2EsyW90G5lFmZe7H4FqR78noo75pEupq3hwdfshAhwA) to part of the data.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It's really impossible to help with something like this without having your data so that we can run this ourselves.

Comment: @joran Here is a link to the first part of data: https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Deutsch/data?w=AAA2EsyW90G5lFmZe7H4FqR78noo75pEupq3hwdfshAhwA

Comment: That link gives me a 403 error.

Comment: please try this: http://temp-share.com/show/gFHK22S6Y

Comment: It's almost certain that you've got the smoothing parameters set too strongly. `lowess` will return essentially a linear fit in such cases, which is what the red line looks like.   That said, you might be happier just calculating a histogram.  Or a `smooth.spline`

Comment: @Carl Witthoft Thanks for your answer. According to the problem, I must use the lowess method to smooth the data, using the tri-cubic kernel and the span should be 0.01. I did not find the settings for these parametes in smooth.spline. However, I still think that the output from lowess method in R is too strange.

Comment: "According to the problem" ?   Mayhap your teacher is not all that competent in data processing techniques?  Why would someone force the span value to be a given value?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I am reimplementing a paper, and I am using their data. And there they have used span 0.01. Still, I believe that the results of lowess with span 0.01 does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Th [smooth](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/curvefit/smooth.html) function in `matlab` is like a filter ,

```
yy = smooth(y)
yy(1) = y(1)
yy(2) = (y(1) + y(2) + y(3))/3
yy(3) = (y(1) + y(2) + y(3) + y(4) + y(5))/5  ## convolution of size 5
yy(4) = (y(2) + y(3) + y(4) + y(5) + y(6))/5
```

I  think it is better to do a simple smooth here.

Here some attempts using **loess**, **lowesss** with f = 0.2(1/5) and using **smooth.spline**

I am using ggplot2 to plot ( to use geom_jitter with some alpha )

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <-  subset(data, V2 < 5000)
#dat <-  data
xy <- lowess(dat$V1,dat$V2,f = 0.8)
xy <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,xy))

p1<- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x= V1, y = V2))+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .2), alpha= 0.1)+
  geom_smooth()

xy <- lowess(dat$V1,dat$V2,f = 0.2)
xy <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,xy))
xy.smooth <- smooth.spline(dat$V1,dat$V2)
xy.smooth <- data.frame(x= xy.smooth$x,y = xy.smooth$y)

p2 <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x= V1, y = V2))+  
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .2), alpha= 0.1)+
  geom_line(data = xy, aes(x=x, y = y, group = 1 ), color = 'red')+
  geom_line(data = xy.smooth, aes(x=x, y = y, group = 1 ), color = 'blue')

library(gridExtra)               
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still, I believe that the results of lowess with span 0.01 does not make sense.